# Can we move list from one sharepoint site to other sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created list on sharepoint site. Since data is confidential we plan to move list to new sharepoint site.

Can we move list data/ entire list to other site. Require solution to migrate the data.

Thanks,

Mangesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it could be done in multiple ways.

**Using list template** :

Go to list setting page - >Click on "Save list as template" - > Give the File Name and Template Name -> Click the checkbox "Include Content" -> Click on the OK button -> It will take you to the list template gallery "**/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx**"

Download this list template file from this gallery.

Upload this file to template gallery in the target site (from site setting page -> Under the Web designer galleries section  you will get **List templates** , click on this **List templates** link which you will take you to the gallery - upload the new list template  here  )

Go to the List creation page from site content, you can find your new custom template there, just create a list out of that... that's it, done.

**Using the migration tool :**

If you have migration tool like sharegate or Metalogix you can migrate that.

**Using the PnP PowerShell:**

You can even do this using the PnP provisioning template. If you google it you will get a reference on how to do, below is one of the example:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing/"
$ListName = "Project Tasks"
$TemplateFile = "C:\Temp\ListSchema.xml"

#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin



#Get the List schema as Template and export to a File
$Templates = Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -OutputInstance -Handlers Lists
$ListTemplate = $Templates.Lists | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq $ListName }
$Templates.Lists.Clear()
$Templates.Lists.Add($ListTemplate)
Save-PnPProvisioningTemplate -InputInstance $Templates -Out $TemplateFile
```

Source:

[SharePoint Online: Copy List or Document Library to Another Site using PnP PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/02/sharepoint-online-copy-list-document-library-to-another-site-using-powershell.html)

Note :

- After moving your list data to target using any of the above approaches, test your data then if everything works fine, you can delete your source list.

**Using the export and import excel approach (credit to Mangesh Malvankar)**

1. Export the source list items to an excel file.
2. Using that exported excel create a list in the target site(import excel).

Comment: Great. Above options are very helpful and good to know I tried one more option. I just export that list to excel and export back to new SharePoint site and it worked.Thanks for help always.:)

Comment: Hi Mangesh - thanks for sharing Export and Import excel approach, I will include this to above steps, so that all approaches will be in one place, it will help to the upcoming visitors :-)

Comment: Thank you Habibur

Answer (score 1):

There are some options for your reference:

1. Use "Save list as template" and include content, then upload to destination site list template, then create a new list using this template.

   Reference:[Manage list templates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393)

   Note: You should enable scripting to use list templates.

   Reference:[Allow or prevent custom script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script)
2. Use Third-party tool as ShareGate to migrate the list.

   Reference: [Copy a List in SharePoint or Office 365](https://sharegate.com/blog/copy-list-in-sharepoint-to-office365-tool)
3. Use PowerShell to go through the source list and add items to destination.

   Reference: [Copy list items to another list in SharePoint Online](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-copy-list-items-to-another-list-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Thanks Emily for providing all the references