# How to copy list item from one site to another site?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, 2016, event-receivers, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have one task list in my site collection. In that list I will assign tasks to users (5 users are there).

Each user have one own site. Whatever tasks I am assigning that they have to see in their own sites. In their sites they will update their task status In Progress or Complete. Everything should update in the source list (my site collection). That means task status assigned should change whatever they updated. I am using SharePoint 2016 on-premises. How to achieve it?

Shall I create through event receiver? For ex.When new item is created that item should dispaly in 5 sites. I am not using REST API and all. Shall I create 2013 workflow for that?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just share the same list? Your solution is creating data redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are you trying to have 5 duplicate lists for each user?

Are you trying to copy the list structure across the sites or 1 list item?

You can use PowerAutomate or PnP.PowerShell to trigger an event when a new item is created and replicate the info on the other lists.

Ref: [Can we move list from one sharepoint site to other sharepoint site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278678/can-we-move-list-from-one-sharepoint-site-to-other-sharepoint-site)